# Newb Shell - How to get response in a variable

Tags: json, shell, variables, wget

Just a quick question to solve an issue I've been facing for days now: how to get an wget json response in a shell variable?

I have so far a wget command like this:

```
wget "http://IP:PORT/webapi/auth.cgi?account=USER&passwd=PASSWD"
```

The server reponse is normally something like:

```
{"data":{"sid":"9O4leaoASc0wgB3J4N01003"},"success":true}
```

What I'd like to do is to grep the sid value in a variable (as it is used as login ticket), but also the success value in order to ensure that the command has been executed correctly...

I think it is a very easy command to build, but I've never practised wget/http reponse in shell command...

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT: Thanks for your help. I did gave a try to both answers, but I am having the same error message (whatever I do):

```
--2022-07-16 14:21:38--  http://xxxxxxxx:port/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=3&account=USER&passwd=PWD&session=SurveillanceStation&format=sid
Connecting to 192.168.1.100:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=3&account=USER&passwd=PASSWD&session=SurveillanceStation&format=sid: Permission denied

Cannot write to `auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=3&account=USER&passwd=PASSWD&session=SurveillanceStation&format=sid' (Permission denied).
```

The annoying thing: execution the URL from a web browser works just fine... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can first store the result of `wget` command in variable and then use it:

```
VAR=$(wget "http://IP:PORT/webapi/auth.cgi?account=USER&passwd=PASSWD")
```

and then using `jq` extract from JSON file:

```
sid=$(echo $VAR|jq .data.sid)
success=$(echo $VAR|jq .success)
```

If you have problem with execution of `wget` you can try something like:

```
wget -O output_file 'http://xxxxxxxx:port/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=3&account=USER&passwd=PWD&session=SurveillanceStation&format=sid'
```

and then set variables:

```
sid=$(jq .data.sid output_file )
success=$(jq .success output_file )
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why I am facing this Permission Denied error. Thus I gave a try to save cookie on a dedicated folder... And it works just fine :)

The final command lloks like:

```
VAR=$(wget -q --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies "/var/tmp/cookie_tmp" -O- "http://IP:PORT/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=login&version=1&account=USER&passwd=PWD&session=SurveillanceStation");
```

Thanks for your help (I learned a lot about sed ;) )

Answer (score -1):

So this can be done using the stream editor or "sed". There is a lot to learn but for this post here is an idea of a code:

```
sid=$(wget <your url> | sed 's/.*sid":"\(.*\)"},.*/\1/')
success=$(wget <your url> | sed 's/.*success":\(.*\)}/\1/')
```

This will create 2 variables `$sid` and `$success`.

you can learn more about sed in depth [here](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Hope this helped!